# Кавычки экранируются в джумле

Tags: joomla, php, экранирование

Здравствуйте! До этого все было нормально, а сейчас не могу сохранить документ, как нужно, т.к. кавычки при сохранении в джумле почему-то экранируются. 
Код:

```
<div class="\&quot;cena5\&quot;">
<p class="\&quot;c\&quot;">Стоимость услуги 1500 рублей/час</p>
</div>
```

И, следовательно, стили не выполняются. Не пойму, в чем причина. Помогите, плиз.

**Обновление**

Версия Joomla! 3.0.3, классы cena5, c, кавычек в имени классов нет, заменять не пробовала (сейчас попробую), раньше все с двойными отлично сохранялось, никаких изменений не вносила... Редактор стоит по умолчанию, есть варианты CodeMirror, TinyMCE, пробовала их поставить, но выдается ошибка.

---

Одинарные кавычки все равно заменяются двойными и экранируются... Нашла название редактора - tinymce.

Comment: @Регина, какая версия Joomla?   
Какой классы пытаетесь добавить?  
В его имени есть кавычки?  
Пробовали заменять кавычки на одинарные?  
В каком WYSIWYG редакторе сохраняете документ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Регина](/users/3765/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)](/users/3765/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0), попробуйте проинициализировать редактор вот так:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    entity_encoding : "raw"
});
```

Или попробуйте отключить `code cleanup` в настройках плагина.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!